# r longest line for each polygon spatial dataframe?

Tags: r, geospatial

how can i get the length of the longest line (side) of each polygon? what package would be least problematic? I wonder if there is any function other than iterating point by point (some dummy example below)? Other than that I wonder if there is any method of getting bearings and or angles of each segment versus neighbours, but as some experts are overly sensitive about asking only one question at a time I will leave it for any other time;) Thanks in advance

```
r1 = cbind(c(180114, 180553, 181127, 180114), c(332349, 332057, 332342, 332349))
r2 = cbind(c(180042, 180545, 180553,  180042), c(332373, 332026, 331426, 332373))
r3 = cbind(c(179110, 179907, 180433, 179110),  c(331086, 330620, 330494, 331086))
r4 = cbind(c(180304, 180403,179632,180304),  c(332791, 333204, 333635, 332791))
sr1=Polygons(list(Polygon(r1)),"r1")
sr2=Polygons(list(Polygon(r2)),"r2")
sr3=Polygons(list(Polygon(r3)),"r3")
sr4=Polygons(list(Polygon(r4)),"r4")
sr=SpatialPolygons(list(sr1,sr2,sr3,sr4))
srdf=SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(sr, data.frame(cbind(1:4,5:2),
                                             row.names=c("r1","r2","r3","r4")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an R package called [GeoAxe](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geoaxe/geoaxe.pdf) you can split geospatial objects into pieces. Once you have the segments individually, you can use another package called [SpatialLines](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sp/versions/1.2-5/topics/SpatialLines) to get the segments' lengths. From here you can select the greatest one.

A possible downside of this method for you is that the data must be a spatial format e.g. .shp for input but luckily there is also a package for [creating these](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html).

Comment: GeoAxe is for area, not perimeter. What I need is basically a tool that gets 4 lines out of a rectangle and checks out which one is the longest, providing its length.  I can do it iterating coordinates, but I thought the task to be so common that there must be a library for it

Answer (score 0):

Does this help ?

```
splitPolygon <- function(x){
  st_segment = function(r){st_linestring(t(matrix(unlist(r), 2, 2)))}
  m <- data.frame(st_coordinates(x)[, 1:2])
  nr <- nrow(m)
  m2 <- cbind(m[-nr,], m[-1,])
  names(m2) <- c("Xstart", "Ystart", "Xend", "Yend")
 m3 <- rbind(m2,
             data.frame(Xstart = m$Xend[nr],
                        Ystart = m$Yend[nr],
                        Xend = m$Xend[1],
                        Yend = m$Yend))
 m3$geom = st_sfc(sapply(1:nrow(m3), 
                         function(i){st_segment(m3[i,])},simplify=FALSE))
 st_sf(m3, crs = st_crs(x))
}

longest_side_of_polygon <- function(x){
  df <- splitPolygon(x)
  l <- st_length(df)
  lmat <- st_coordinates(df[which.max(l), ])[,1:2]
  st_sfc(st_linestring(rbind(lmat[1,], lmat[2,])),
         crs = st_crs(x))
}
```